# Google Sheets Line Chart: connect missing points

Tags: google-sheets, charts, line

How do I connect missing points in a Google Sheets Line Chart with a straight line?
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X3BhDyideX-7kyJ9Y-7xvV1naAwWd9eDPfPy3pP94Ic/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your situation, how about checking "Plot null values"? When this is checked, the following result can be obtained.

[image]

When you want to check it using Google Apps Script, you can also use the following script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  const c = chart.modify().setOption("interpolateNulls", "true").build();
  sheet.updateChart(c);
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart?csw=1#Configuration_Options)